# How to marshal specific fields from objects in a List with MOXy at runtime

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, marshalling, moxy

I need to marshal an collection List to `xml` but I want the user to choose which fields will be marshaled from the List's objects. Here is a better explaination of what I am trying to do.

First I have an POJO called **Server**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Server {

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)  private String vendor;
    @XmlElement(nillable=true)  private int memory;
    @XmlElement(nillable=true)  private String cpu;
//getters and setters
}
```

Then in my applications I have this method which is doing the marshal job.
Note that this implementation is based on this [Creating a Generic List Wrapper in JAXB](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/creating-generic-list-wrapper-in-jaxb.html)

and [MOXy's Object Graphs - Partial Models on the Fly to/from XML & JSON](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-partial-models-on.html)

```
    protected void marshalCollection(Object collection,OutputStream os) throws Exception {
        //The output list contains the name of the Server.class fields to be                           
        //marshaled
        List<String> output = (List<String>) getContext()
                .getHttpServletRequest().getAttribute("output");

        Class<?> cls = Class.forName("my.package.Server");

        //This list contains the Server objects to be marshaled
        List ls = (List) collection;

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Wrapper.class, cls);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        QName qName = new QName("servers");
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(ls);
        JAXBElement<Wrapper> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<Wrapper>(qName,
                Wrapper.class, wrapper);

        ObjectGraph outputInfo = JAXBHelper.getJAXBContext(jc)
                .createObjectGraph(Wrapper.class);

        Subgraph subg = outputInfo.addSubgraph("server");

        for (String o : output) {
            subg.addAttributeNodes(o);
        }

        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH, outputInfo);
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, os);

    }
```

Here is my Wrapper class

```
public class Wrapper<T> {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    private List<T> items;

    public Wrapper() {
        items = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public Wrapper(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }


    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately I get back an empty xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<servers/>
```

An example of what I want to get back is below

If the **output** list contains "memory" and "cpu" and the **ls** list contains two Server objects

```
Server[vendor=HP,memory=4096,cpu=intel]
Server[vendor=IBM,memory=2048,cpu=amd]
```

then the xml that I want to get back is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<servers>
    <server>
        <memory>4096</memory>
        <cpu>intel</cpu>
    </server>
    <server>
        <memory>2048</memory>
        <cpu>amd</cpu>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Can anyone help me find what I am doing wrong? 
Is there any other way that I could marshal only selected fields from my Server objects in the List?

Thanks

Comment: Try an assertion just above for (String o : output) to the effect of assert output.size() > 0 : "No strings in output!";

Comment: @BillHorvathII I have the assertion in my code. I just didn't include it in my post here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hit a bug in how we handle Object Graphs with `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` in MOXy.  You can use the following bug to track our progress on this issue.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/423953

### Workaround

You could leverage JAXB with StAX for this use case.  StAX will be used to write the wrapper element, and then you can marshal the individual instances of `Server` to it.  Note how the Object Graph is created changes slightly.

```
    XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamWriter xsw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
    xsw.writeStartDocument();
    xsw.writeStartElement("servers");

    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);

    ObjectGraph outputInfo = JAXBHelper.getJAXBContext(jc)
        .createObjectGraph(Server.class);
    for (String o : output) {
        outputInfo.addAttributeNodes(o);
    }

    marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH, outputInfo);

    for(Object item : ls) {
        marshaller.marshal(item, xsw);
    }
    xsw.writeEndElement();
    xsw.writeEndDocument();
    xsw.close();
```